# Operator/Syntax Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, vb6

I am executing SQL in VB6 and this is the string that I am using, where I define currFA as a number 1. I've been debugging and working at this since it's using inner joins and unions (it's a query I made in Access that I am trying to put into VB6 to run). Right now, I'm getting an operator missing error on the run.

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [~ALLCBLEQ].Equipment, [~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX" _
& "FROM ([~FIRE_AREAS] INNER JOIN [~ALLTARGETS] ON [~FIRE_AREAS].FULL_ID = [~ALLTARGETS].FA) INNER JOIN ([~ALLRWCBL] INNER JOIN [~ALLCBLEQ] ON" _
& "[~ALLRWCBL].Cable = [~ALLCBLEQ].Cables) ON [~ALLTARGETS].TARGET = [~ALLRWCBL].Cable" _
& "WHERE ((([~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX) = '" & currFA & "'))" _
& "UNION" _
& "SELECT DISTINCT [~ALLCBLEQ].Equipment, [~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX" _
& "FROM [~FIRE_AREAS] INNER JOIN (([~ALLTARGETS] INNER JOIN [~ALLRWCBL] ON [~ALLTARGETS].TARGET=[~ALLRWCBL].Raceway) INNER JOIN [~ALLCBLEQ] ON" _
& "[~ALLRWCBL].Cable=[~ALLCBLEQ].Cables) ON [~FIRE_AREAS].FULL_ID=[~ALLTARGETS].FA" _
& "WHERE ((([~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX) = '" & currFA & "'));"
```

Any help on the error and syntax improvement tips are greatly appreciated! Still learning!

Thanks!

Comment: Cthulhu only knows whether this is your real problem but you need spaces either at the end of each line or at the start of the next e.g. x = "Select ..." & " FROM..."

Comment: You said 'currFA' is a number - but what is '((([~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX' -- is it defined as a number? If yes, then you need to remove the single-quotes from = '" & currFA & "'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string has no spaces between the lines so when you write:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [~ALLCBLEQ].Equipment, [~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX" _
& "FROM ([~FIRE_AREAS] …
```

That becomes a SQL string like

```
SELECT DISTINCT [~ALLCBLEQ].Equipment, [~FIRE_AREAS].INDEXFROM ([~FIRE_AREAS] …
```

Which is obviously invalid SQL because there's no space between `INDEX` and `FROM`.

An easy solution is just to put a space before each closing quote (or after each open quote):

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [~ALLCBLEQ].Equipment, [~FIRE_AREAS].INDEX " _
    & "FROM ([~FIRE_AREAS] …
```

However, If you find yourself writing relatively complex queries like this, I would recommend that you consider converting them to stored procedures or views instead.

Comment: Thanks! Silly oversight.